# slashbox.sty not found error

Tags: packages, ubuntu, linux

When compiling with Kile I get the error

> LaTeX Error: File 'slashbox.sty' not found.

Comment: According to https://ctan.org/pkg/slashbox the package is not in TeX Live (for licensing reasons), so you need to install it manually. But do you really need it? I'd avoid that table style with great care.

Comment: There is a newer package `diagbox` which [is on CTAN and in TeX Live](https://ctan.org/pkg/diagbox).

Comment: There is also an command `\diagox` in `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.